# How To Display Image instead of Taxonomy name using Views to display my nodes?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I Have Entity Module and already have a Taxonomy Vocabulary with terms and an Image Field created. Each term has a unique image.

I Have a Content Type with a Term Reference field set to allow multiple selections of my Vocabulary.

I now want to have my Nodes displayed in a Views Table, Title, Node Image, and Taxonomy terms as images rather than their names.

How do I make this possible? Here is a link to what the site currently is (HTML Table rather than a view - very limiting and slow for updating). http://dev.destinationsound.net/

The different color circles are what will be taxonomy terms.

Drupal 7

Note: This is not for a taxonomy term page but rather a list of nodes that have taxonomy terms associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view of the appropriate nodes
2. Set the view output type to be "table"
3. Create a "relationship" in the view between node and taxonomy term
4. Now you can add the image field from the term to your views output
5. If you use multiple vocabularies, add a filter to select just the vocabulary you are interested in.

If you don't already have the imagecache module installed, I recommend it as it will let you control the size of the displayed image.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding a relationship and what it did, since one node has multiple terms, it displays the node multiple times, once for each term it has. I chose "Content: Taxonomy terms on node", selected required and selected the vocabulary I want associated.

Comment: Its not an issue of multiple vocabularies, rather multiple terms within my vocabulary. Each Node has up to 6 terms that can be simultaniously selected. This is resulting in repeated entries of the same node, one for each node. In my example I have 2 test nodes. The view outputs 3 of each node (6 total) because each node has 3 terms selected. I want one listing for each node but with their multiple terms showing.

Comment: You can solve this in 1 of two ways:

- Select the "unique" setting in the view
- Enable the "aggregation" feature

Comment: Better answer: You can solve this by enabling the "aggregation" feature, and then choose an aggregation method for your taxonomy field, e.g. "group results together".

Comment: Almost there. It now only shows 2 nodes, but now only one of the term images is showing. There should be all three

Comment: Probably you just need to pick a different aggregation method.